# Remove logger from slf4j (reverse of getLogger)?

Tags: java, memory, logging, slf4j

How can I remove a Logger?

`slf4j` internally stores every logger ever created. With a long running application, loggers pile up in `slf4j` over time.
Currently (`v1.7.7`), using `getLogger` via `slf4j-api`, the simple logger factory or `log4j` factory also stores the new instance in a hash map. But those logger objects are never removed.

(Note, the question is not about the actual logging framework, but about the slf4j binding.)

Comment: What do you actually want to know about the slf4j binding? I believe you can configure the log-level of Classes by name (or package) in the configuration family. I think there's probably a programmatic method. There maybe a JMX binding. Basically, in what context do you want to disable the logging?

Comment: The bindings are the root of the problem: they store every logger (ever created) internally in a concurrent hashmap. Now, if the application only requests loggers per class, you end up with, e.g., 300 logger instances, that's fine. But if the names are based on application context, then a logger that was formerly used, but not anymore, will be kept there forever.

Comment: @SittingAtTheBay Did you find a solution for that?